# Neo4j Query Performance Issue

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have some performance issue using a specific Cypher Command.

I look for R nodes not directly connected to a specific set of nodes of type I (Here, nodes with index field at "79" and "4") and I want to maximize the field "score" :

```
MATCH (r:R), (i0:I { index:"79" }), (i1:I { index:"4" })
WHERE NOT r--i0 AND NOT r--i1
RETURN r.index
ORDER BY r.score DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The query is executed generally in 1250ms.
If I remove the ORDER BY clause, the request time goes down to 130ms.
The order clause iterates on nearly 3300 elements.

Any idea how I can speed up that request ? I am sure there is a way to use another syntax to perform this search.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is normal, by removing the **ORDER BY**, he will return you the 5 first nodes he can match. 
By adding the ORDER BY, it forces to load all possible matching nodes, depending of the amount of "R" nodes the time will increase.

Now :

Did you "profiled" your query with **PROFILE**

do you have indexes/constraints on I:index ?

Can you change slightly your query to :

```
MATCH (r:R), (i0:I { index:"79" }), (i1:I { index:"4" })
WHERE NOT EXISTS((r)--(i0)) 
AND NOT EXISTS((r)--(i1))
RETURN r.index
ORDER BY r.score DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I have a unique constraint on index fields on both I and R. I had nearly the same request speed with your request version. Then I updated to 2.3.0-M01, and I have a 150ms request time. Here you have the profile data : [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tKrNQe0W)

Answer (score 2):

Which version do you use? try to update to the latest one, also please share your visual query plan by prefixing your query with `PROFILE``

Change it to:

```
MATCH (i0:I { index:"79" }), (i1:I { index:"4" })
MATCH (r:R) 
WHERE NOT r--i0 AND NOT r--i1
WITH r
ORDER BY r.score DESC
LIMIT 5
RETURN r.index
```